# Webpack configuration file for multi page application

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My team work on a multi page website and so far we used JS and some angularjs.
We thought to give a try to `Reactjs` so we added one page written in `jsx` and we also used `webpack` for the bundling (compiled by babel).

Now that we have that one page we want to expand our work with Reactjs. The first thing we have in mind is to split that (rather long) file. What does it actually means? We defined some components in it and for the first step we want to take each one of them to an individual file. My question is regarding to `Webpack`'s entry section. I couldn't find any better approach than to add each and every file written in `jsx` explicitly to the entry section. It is even described in `Wepback` documentation: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application

Is it really the only way to do that?
In a few weeks I expect us to have at least 50 files containing pages, components and other stuff. Does a webpack file in a big project contains all the files explicitly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add every jsx file to the entry section.  You only need to add your *entry* point.

For the component you are building, you probably have the main component (the very top, e.g., App.js) importing or requiring other (sub)components.  You only need to add the top-level or main component to the entry section.

The main job that webpack does is traverse down the module graph (each `import` or `require`) and roll everything up into a bundle based on the top-level component (usually the whole app).

Answer (score 0):

use imports and exports in your js files and have 1 main file that webpack looks at